# Get Textarea scroll percentage via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So I have a split view markdown editor I am building in JS for Win8. On the left hand side is an textarea field (with a title above it so it's not the full height of the screen). On the right I have a div containing the output of what the markdown preview looks like. This preview window is the full height of the screen. When I scroll the left textarea I want to keep the right preview panel in sync. I can easily do this by calculating the scroll percentage of the textarea then scrolling the preview div to the same position.

Right now I am suck on the fact that I can't figure out the max scroll value for the textarea. All of the examples I have seen for keeping two elements in sync when you scroll involve two divs with overflow set. So on the div you can quickly determine the actual height.

Is there a way of getting an textarea's max scroll size (not the actual size of the textarea) so I can calculate the percentage? The only solution I could think of was to make a hidden div the same exact size of the textarea and output the contents to that, then sync the textarea scrolling to that, determine the percentage and then apply it to the larger preview div. My fear is that this will have a performance impact on my app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `element.scrollTop` / (`element.scrollHeight` - `element.offsetHeight`) * 100

Comment: Thanks, I was doing that but I tracked down the root of my problem to selecting the textarea with jQuery. For some reason when I do $('#input').scrollHeight is was undefined but selecting the element manually document.getElementById('input'); allowed me to access the scrollHeight.